# how could i use useEffect to replace componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I would like to use `useEffect()`to instead of `componentWillMount()`, but I found the hook can not use in class components, so I change the code as Function component, but it will get more error for the whole component, all code with this.xxx are getting an error, how could I edit below code to make it work? Please help me. Below code is working fine with `componentWillMount()`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.less';
import { formateDate } from '../../utils/dateUtils';
import memoryUtils from '../../utils/memoryUtils';
import { reqWeather } from '../../api/index';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import menuList from '../../config/menuConfig';

class Header extends Component {
  state = {
    currentTime: formateDate(Date.now()),
    dayPictureUrl: '',
    weather: '',
  };
  getTime = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const currentTime = formateDate(Date.now());
      this.setState({ currentTime });
    }, 1000);
  };
  getWeather = async () => {
    const { dayPictureUrl, weather } = await reqWeather('Auckland');
    this.setState({ dayPictureUrl, weather });
  };
  getTitle = (props) => { 
    const path = this.props.location.pathname;
    let title;
    menuList.forEach(item => {
      if (item.key === path) {
        title = item.title;
      } else if (item.children) {
        const cItem = item.children.find(cItem => cItem.key === path);
        if (cItem) {
          title = cItem.title;
        }
      }
    });
    return title;
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTime();
    this.getWeather();
  }
  render() {
    const { currentTime, dayPictureUrl, weather } = this.state;
    const username = memoryUtils.user.username;
    const title = this.getTitle();
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="header-top">
          <span>Welcome, {username}</span>
          <a href>logout</a>
        </div>
        <div className="header-bottom">
          <div className="header-bottom-left">{title}</div>
          <div className="header-bottom-right">
            <span>{currentTime}</span>
            <img src={dayPictureUrl} alt="weather" />
            <span>{weather}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Header)
```

Comment: A `useEffect` hook with empty dependency, `useEffect(() => {...}, [])`, is the functional component equivalent of `componentDidMount`. Functional components are instanceless, so there is no `this`. SO isn't a code writing service, please attempt the conversion from class-based to functional component and if you get stuck we can help you with specific issue(s).

Comment: @Keida, please check this documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html . You can write it on your own surly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've converted from react classes to react hooks I hope it help, I haven't tested because I don't have the external files that you have but I hope it helps otherwise just comment on this solution ;)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './index.less';
import { formateDate } from '../../utils/dateUtils';
import memoryUtils from '../../utils/memoryUtils';
import { reqWeather } from '../../api/index';
import { withRouter, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import menuList from '../../config/menuConfig';



function Header(){
const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(formateDate(Date.now()))
const [dayPictureUrl, setDayPictureUrl] = useState('')
const [weather, setWeather] = useState('')
const location = useLocation();
const path = location.pathname;

useEffect(() => {
    getTime();
    getWeather();
},[]);


const getTime = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const currentTime = formateDate(Date.now());
      setCurrentTime(currentTime)
    }, 1000);
  };
const   getWeather = async () => {
    const { dayPictureUrl, weather } = await reqWeather('Auckland');
    setDayPictureUrl(dayPictureUrl)
    setWeather(weather)

  };
const  getTitle = (props) => { 
    let title;
    menuList.forEach(item => {
      if (item.key === path) {
        title = item.title;
      } else if (item.children) {
        const cItem = item.children.find(cItem => cItem.key === path);
        if (cItem) {
          title = cItem.title;
        }
      }
    });
    return title;
  };
  const username = memoryUtils.user.username;
  const title = getTitle();
  return (<div className="header">
  <div className="header-top">
    <span>Welcome, {username}</span>
    <a href>logout</a>
  </div>
  <div className="header-bottom">
    <div className="header-bottom-left">{title}</div>
    <div className="header-bottom-right">
      <span>{currentTime}</span>
      <img src={dayPictureUrl} alt="weather" />
      <span>{weather}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  )
}


export default Header
```

Comment: Thanks man, i got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined inconst path = this.props.location.pathname;

Comment: There is no `this` in function components, and there are several issues with dependencies in the `useEffect` in this. `useEffect` shouldn't be considered a replacement for `componentDidMount` as it works very differently and you should consider it in a different way.

Comment: @Keida you are right, I forgot to edit that part let me fix it on the code ;)

Comment: @ZacharyHaber True, `useEffect` isn't a replacement for `componentDidMount`. It's *actually* a replacement for `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @Keida, I just fixed it, hope it helps!

Comment: @Rene Polo, thanks man, your code is all most correct,but it still has small issues, so i fixed it by myself.i move `const location = useLocation();`and `const path = location.pathname;` to the beginning with useState.also i delete `[title,setTitle]=userState(’‘)`and add `const title=getTitle()`, let me know if you have got more effective solvtion for it.

Comment: @Rene Polo the useEffect() should be  `useEffect(() => {getTime();getWeather();getTitle();}); `if i use useState with Tile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my go at converting the function to using hooks.

One of the best things about hooks is that they can all be called as many times as you like, which allows us to separate the concerns of a component into logical blocks.

`useEffect` shouldn't be considered a direct replacement for componentDidMount as it works differently. The closest would actually be `useLayoutEffect` because of the timing of it matches `componentDidMount` and `componentdDidUpdate`. More detail on the difference between the two: [useEffect vs useLayoutEffect](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect). Although you should in general use `useEffect` primarily.

Getting used to hooks requires a bit of a shift in how you think of components, but in my opinion, it's worth the effort to switch!

```
import React, {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from 'react';
import './index.less';
import { formateDate } from '../../utils/dateUtils';
import memoryUtils from '../../utils/memoryUtils';
import { reqWeather } from '../../api/index';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import menuList from '../../config/menuConfig';

export default function Header (props){
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(formateDate(Date.now()));
  useEffect(()=>{
    const intervalId = setInterval(()=>{
      setCurrentTime(formateDate(Date.now()));
    },1000)
    // Make sure to cleanup your effects!
    return ()=>{clearInterval(intervalId)}
  },[])

  const [dayPictureUrl, setDayPictureUrl] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    const getWeather = async () => {
      const { dayPictureUrl, weather } = await reqWeather('auckland');
      setDayPictureUrl(dayPictureUrl);
      setWeather(weather);
    };
    // Assuming that we want to have the weather dynamically based on a passed in prop (i.e. props.city), or a state.
    getWeather();
  }, []);

  // useLocation gets the location via a hook from react router dom
  const location = useLocation();
  const title = useMemo(()=>{
    // useMemo as this can be an expensive calculation depending on the length of menuList
    // menuList is always a constant value, so it won't change
    const path = location.pathname;
    let title;
    menuList.forEach(item => {
      if (item.key === path) {
        title = item.title;
      } else if (item.children) {
        const cItem = item.children.find(cItem => cItem.key === path);
        if (cItem) {
          title = cItem.title;
        }
      }
    });
    return title;
  },[location.pathname])
  
  const username = memoryUtils.user.username;

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-top">
        <span>Welcome, {username}</span>
        <a href>logout</a>
      </div>
      <div className="header-bottom">
        <div className="header-bottom-left">{title}</div>
        <div className="header-bottom-right">
          <span>{currentTime}</span>
          <img src={dayPictureUrl} alt="weather" />
          <span>{weather}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```